# Solve $(\sin (\theta)+\cos(\theta))^2= \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I came across this problem:

> Solve for $\theta$ (between value $0$ and $2\pi$) where  $$(\sin (\theta)+\cos(\theta))^2= \frac{3}{2}$$

I started by expanding the left side to get $\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2{\theta}+\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) = \frac{3}{2}$ then changed sin&cos squared sum into $1$ and used double angle formula for sin to get $\sin(2\theta)=1$.
Then I continued to get the solution $\theta=\pi/4 +2\pi n$ but the answer is incorrect.

Can I get help on understanding my mistake here?

Comment: The first expansion of the left side is wrong.

Comment: @jjagmath Thank you. I really thought I was missing something important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your thought process is correct overall but you've made a mistake while expanding the left side. More precisely, you should've done

$$ (\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta))^2 = \sin^2(\theta) + 2 \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1 + 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) = 1 + \sin(2\theta). $$

Hence, it follows that

$$ (\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta))^2 = \frac{3}{2} \Longleftrightarrow \sin(2\theta) = \frac{1}{2} .$$

Solving the latter equation, you obtain

$$ 2\theta = \frac{\pi}{6} + 2\pi n \quad \text{ or } \quad 2\theta = \frac{5\pi}{6} + 2\pi n, $$

which is equivalent to

$$ \theta = \frac{\pi}{12} + \pi n \quad \text{ or } \quad \theta = \frac{5\pi}{12} + \pi n. $$

Since you're only interested in values of $\theta$ such that $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, your solutions are

$$ \Big\{ \frac{\pi}{12}, \frac{5\pi}{12}, \frac{13\pi}{12},\frac{17\pi}{12} \Big\}. $$

Comment: You forgot about $\theta = \frac{13 \pi}{12}$.

Comment: Should be fine now @BenSteffan